# On the mechanics of updating mythology?

Tags: source-request

So I have the impression that in India a lot of real life events were glorified in Indian history and entered mythology (like the Mahabharata, etc? It recounts the Kurukshetra war, which is believed to have taken place around 3000 BCE).

There must be some times when a civilization can and can't update it's mythology.

What would be good reading material for understanding the mechanics and nature of updating mythology?

Comment: It's far from being an *ancient* phenomenon. Perhaps research [Joseph Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith) and [Brigham Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigham_Young)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens thanks. I hope the question is still valid? I'm looking for a thesis where someone proposes conditions which enable updating of mythology

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. Focus on the main one.

Comment: @Jos updated the question. Is it better?

Comment: It is, but book recommendations are not something you're going to get here. Sorry.

Comment: FWIW, India has special issues with ancient history, owing to the fact that there's no known native writing (that we know how to read) until about 1500 BCE. Everything we know about Indian History much before then is either a recording of popular myth, or written by (sometimes hostile) outsiders.

Comment: "There must be some times when a civilization can and can't update it's mythology." Why must that be? Why assume there must be a "mechanics" to this aspect of history where you've shown no evidence of a mechanical pattern?

Comment: @T.E.D. can I migrate this question?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't think the premise is right. Mythmaking happens all the time, and is currently happening as we speak. I'd say much of the founding of the US, the Civil War, and the World Wars has entered into a popular mythology, of sorts. We're driven, as a species, to create a narrative and then find meaning in that narrative, which is really what mythology is about.

Comment: @cmw is religious mythology any different?

Comment: It can depend. You have to remember that for cultures like India, there's really no difference between popular mythology and religious mythology. Hinduism wasn't a separate religion, per se, so much as it was a shared set of beliefs about the past. Same with most traditional "religions."

Comment: I'm not sure of any sources on "updating" mythology just yet, but I can comb through some things and get back to you on that. Ping me again if I take too long.

Comment: @cmw sure thing! Thanks :)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous For Judaism and Christianity the "updating" (i.e. the texts considered sacred, or the canon) happened when there was a significant *and* real event which requires an updating of the theology of that religion (example: Babylonian exile, Persian "reprieve" allowing the 2nd Temple to be built, the coming, crucifixion, and resurrection of Jesus the Messiah).  About "can" or "cannot", I think it's more a function of the authority of the "myth keeper" (i.e. the religious authority).  But I don't have a good reading material on it, hence this comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @cmw any progress? (Hey)

Comment: Thanks for the ping. We've come a long way, but incidentally, ritual theory is back as a compelling argument for the explanation of myths. You might want to start [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=M_MNFaJ-UacC&pg=PA58&dq=changing+myths+to+suit+politics&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0#v=onepage&q=changing%20myths%20to%20suit%20politics&f=false). Sorry, work's been hectic, but I can add to this again shortly.

Answer (score 1):

### New Voices

Mythology gets updated when new voices retell the stories. There are a number of differences between the Lord of the Rings books and the Peter Jackson Lord of the Rings movies, but both are highly regarded by fans.

Similarly, comic book superheros are frequently updated when new artists retell the stories with new tones and different focus.

So to find times when Mythology have changed, look for times when new people have encountered the stories (example: migration) or times when new people have had a change to tell the stories (example: social change).

### Hindu Specific

The Indo-Aryan [migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_migrations) would be an important period in the formation of Hindu mythology. The (presumably well established) Indo-European herding culture mythology would change as it encountered Central Asia farming cultures ~2,200 BC. Wikipedia suggests that the Indo-European Sky Father (Zeus / Odin) was absorbed into an existing Central Asian Indra cult to create the Vedic Indra.

As the migrating Indo-Aryans settled down and merged with existing Punjab cultures, it probably would have undergone another significant shift. This would be around the time that the first [Vedic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_period) myths were written down, ~1,500 BC.

The introduction of amhisa after the rise of [Jainism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism) would be another period of change for Hindu myth (cira 600 BC). This leads to the shift from cow sacrifice to cow veneration. The later rise of and interaction with other world religions - Buddhism and Islam certainly -  would also influence Hindu myth, but I'll cut this off here before we get too long.